# Centering a button group in Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, centering

Trying to get a button group to center in the middle of a `col-md-6` div, and adding `.center` or `.center-block` or `.text-center` is not working. None of the above also work when applied to a container div above it.

HTML:

```
<div class="btn-toolbar" role="toolbar">
  <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">North America</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">South America</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Middle East</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Africa</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">East Asia</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">South Asia</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, the issue was that I was using a `.btn-toolbar` to surround, which pulls it to the left.